# Creating loadmore option using angular http service

Tags: angularjs

I am hoping to get some help with this.

Working on an AngularJS (v1.5.11) site. I have a service (articleservice) that provides data to the article controller.

What I would like to do is fetch data in batches of 10, and update the data upon request, in essence, implementing a load more option. Most of the examples I have looked tend to do their heavy lifting in the controller and not service.

My current service is as allows:

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app.articles').factory('articleservice', articleservice);
    articleservice.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'exception'];
    /* @ngInject */
    function articleservice($http, $q, exception) {
        var urlBase = 'https://mysite.ca/api';
        var service = {
            getArticles: getArticles
        };
        return service;

        function getArticles() {
            return $http.get(urlBase + '/articles').then(success).
            catch(fail);

            function success(response) {
                return response.data;
            }

            function fail(e) {
                return exception.catcher('XHR Failed for getArticles')(e);
            }
        }

    }
})();
```

I would like to pass some parameters to my HTTP service.

likethe page number of the data resource,

eg.  `$http.get(urlBase + '/article**?page=0**')`

In addition, I would like the value the f page to be updated whenever a user clicks the  load more button.

eg.  `$http.get(urlBase + '/article**?page=1**')`

Here is my controller:

```
 (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.articles')
        .controller('ArticleController', ArticleController);

    ArticleController.$inject = ['$q', 'articleservice', 'logger'];
    /* @ngInject */
    function ArticleController($q, articleservice, logger) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'Article';

        // I want to pass the following parameters to articleservice.
        vm.per_page = 10; // restrict intiaail results to 10
        vm.page = 0; // 
        vm.more = false; // if vm.articles.length is greater than 10, then change this to true.

        vm.articles = [];

        activate();

        function activate() {
            var promises = [getArticle()];
            return $q.all(promises).then(function () {
                logger.info('Activated Article View');
            });
        }

        function getArticle() {
            return articleservice.getArticle().then(function (data) {
                vm.articles = data.nodes;
                return vm.articles;
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

My view

```
 <article ng-repeat="node in vm.articles | unique: 'node.nid'" class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="landing" >
                        <a ui-sref="article({ nid:node.nid })"> <img class="img-responsive img img-fluid" ng-src="{{node.node.featured_image.src}}" alt="{{node.node.featured_image.alt}}" /> </a>
                        <div class="landing-overlay">
                            <h2>
                <a ui-sref="article{{vm.title}}({ nid:node.nid })"  style="color:#fff; ">                                    
                                {{node.node.title | limitTo: 55 }}{{node.node.title.length > 55 ? '...' : ''}}</a></h2> </div>

                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
            <!--no-help sections ends-->
            <button class="button button-more" ng-click="vm.loadmore()"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Show More</button>
```

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here please try the below :

**Service**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('app.articles').factory('articleservice', articleservice);
articleservice.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'exception'];
/* @ngInject */
function articleservice($http, $q, exception) {
    var urlBase = 'https://mysite.ca/api';
    var service = {
        getArticles: getArticles
    };
    return service;

    function getArticles(pageNo,pageSize) {
        return $http.get(urlBase + '/articles?pageNumber='+pageNo + '&pageSize=' + pageSize).then(success).
        catch(fail);

        function success(response) {
            return response.data;
        }

        function fail(e) {
            return exception.catcher('XHR Failed for getArticles')(e);
        }
    }

}
})();
```

**Controller**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.articles')
    .controller('ArticleController', ArticleController);

ArticleController.$inject = ['$q', 'articleservice', 'logger'];
/* @ngInject */
function ArticleController($q, articleservice, logger) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'Article';

    // I want to pass the following parameters to articleservice.
    vm.per_page = 10; // restrict intial results to 10
    vm.page = 0; // 
    vm.more = false; // if vm.articles.length is greater than 10, then change this to true.

    vm.articles = [];

    // first call to data articles
    activate(0,10);

   vm.loadMore = function (pageNo, pageSize)
   {
      activate(pageNo, pageSize);
   }

    function activate(pageNo, pageSize) {
        var promises = [getArticle(pageNo,pageSize)];
        return $q.all(promises).then(function () {
            logger.info('Activated Article View');
        });
    }

    function getArticle(pageNo, pageSize) {
        return articleservice.getArticle(pageNo, pageSize).then(function (data) {
            vm.articles = data.nodes;
            return vm.articles;
        });
    }
}
})();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Danish. It works! It pulls the first batch of data. Thanks once again.

Comment: yup, the articles service is a good idea for service. Welcome :)

Comment: Thank you so much Danish. It works! Your code pulls the first batch of data. I have updated my question to include the snippet  of the view. I now need to (1) to wire the load more button  and (2) calculate data.length so as to only show the load button only if there is more than one page of data.